# How to use testng.xml

Tags: xml, selenium

Hi i am new to selenium, now i want to run my test suite using  selenium rc and eclipse Ide
i have using ant when i execute, for that time i got error in testNG.xml. so kindly tell me any one how to use testng.xml and give me one sample of testng.xml

## This is my Build.xml

```
<property name="lib.dir"   value="/softwares/lib"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="/softwares/src" />
```

```
<target name="run_testNG" description="Run TestNG">
    <testng classpathref="compile.classpath" haltOnfailure="false">
        <xmlfileset dir="/softwares/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/run_test/" includes="testng.xml" />
    </testng>
</target>
<target name="start-server">
    <java jar="/softwares/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
        <arg line="-timeout 30"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.corporate.com"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="stop-server">
    <get taskname="selenium-shutdown"
        src="http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer"
        dest="result.txt" ignoreerrors="true" />
    <echo taskname="selenium-shutdown" message="DGF Errors during shutdown are expected" />
</target>
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/softwares/selenium/selenium-2.0b2/libs/testng-5.14.1.jar" />
```

===========================

This is my testng.xml

===================

We are getting following errors:

```
Buildfile: build.xml
prepare:
compile:
run_test:
  [waitfor] Wait for proxy server launch
start-server:
run_testNG:
   [testng] [TestNG] [ERROR] 
   [testng] Cannot find class in classpath: com.example.tests
   [testng] The tests failed.
stop-server:
[selenium-shutdown] Getting: http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
[selenium-shutdown] To: /softwares/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/run_test/result.txt
[selenium-shutdown] DGF Errors during shutdown are expected
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Please help me.....we are getting error for "Cannot find class in classpath"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the classpath you launch TestNG with contains your classes.